# How to use ToDictionary with <string, object> dictionary

Tags: c#, string, object, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary that can hold multiple values per key, and I have created an class called `Pair` that consists of two `string`s. I have defined `idDictionary` to contain a `string` as the key, and `Pair` as the value, but I am unsure how to write the `ToDictionary` statement as this concept is new to me, and I couldn't find any examples of this.

```
Dictionary<string, Pair<string, string>> idDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Pair<string, string>>();
```

I know with a regular generic Dictionary of  I would simply use something like this:

```
idDictionary = resultData.Rows.Select(row => row.Split(','))
                              .ToDictionary(id => id[0], id => id[1]);
```

I am not sure how I would implement something similar for the object called `Pair`. Maybe I'm missing something really simple, but many thanks to those with answers.

**EDIT to include full code block and more thorough explanation**

The original code block is here (with a generic dictionary). The reason I am changing this is due to the fact that if there is more than 1 value per key, the application errors out due to duplicate keys.

```
    private List<ImportItem<T>> ProcessReportResult(CSVTable resultData, ICollection<ImportItem<T>> data, Func<T, string> keyFilter)
    {
        WriteLog("{1}{0} records found.{1}", resultData.Rows.Length, Environment.NewLine);

        //key = Order Number; value = Order ID
        var idDictionary = resultData.Rows.Select((row => row.Split(','))).ToDictionary(id => id[0], id => id[1]);
        idDictionary.ForEach(id => WriteLog("Input Id = {0} - Matching record Id = {1}", id.Key, id.Value));
        var processList = data.Where(item => idDictionary.ContainsKey(keyFilter(item.DataItem))).ToList();
        processList.ForEach(item => item.id = idDictionary[keyFilter(item.DataItem)]);
        return processList;
    }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with just using `Tuple`?

Comment: what do you want to be the key and value?

Comment: Could you show some example data and the results you are expecting to get?

Comment: I have just revised to fix some errors in the post.

Comment: Plus to the Tuple. You may also consider a list or collection as the value based on your full requirements (Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A genral solution to get the one to many key value store can be achieved via grouping but that would require to have `value` as List of items. If I try to explain it via your given sample then the query to convert the rows to per key multi value store can be created by:

```
        idDictionary = 
         resultData.Rows
            .GroupBy(row => row.Id, row => row.Split(','))
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

> Update:

Specific solution to your problem. Assuming that data would have structure something like:

```
 List<Row> rows = new List<Row>{
            new Row{
                values = "1,A"
            },
            new Row{
                values = "2,C,D,E"
            },
            new DataRow{
                values = "3,E,X,CV,B"
            },
        };
```

You can use the Group here as well to get the Key, Value(List). Note, Here I have skipped the first value which is already captured as key at index 0.

```
     var idDictionary =
                 rows.GroupBy(row => row.values.Split(',')[0], 
                                  row => row.values.Split(',').Skip(1))
                                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

This will give you the result like:

```
    /* output - 

     |1, (A)|
     |2, (C,D,E)|
     |3, (E,X,CV,B)|

     */
```

Though you have to change the implementation for fetching the values via List.
But this solution will prevent the Program if there are more than one values found per key.

Comment: Vendetta, can you provide an example of how I would change fetching values via list? This has been a big help so far.

Comment: Glad it helped! For fetching values you have to treat the value as List e.g. `idDictionary.ForEach(id => WriteLog("Input Id = {0} - Matching record Id = {1}", id.Key, id.Value));` here id.Value will be a collection of values so you might want to handle them if list have more than one value. if list have single value then `id.Value.First()` would work, for multiple values you can take decision by your business logic.

Comment: Interesting, instead of splitting the dictionary into a string, list combo for key, value could I just then tell it to grab the first value only instead of creating a list?

Comment: Yes you can apply the First() extesion method to get only first value instead of complete list. e.g. ` .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList().First());`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need maybe this simple example will help?

```
 idDictionary = resultData.Rows
                   .Select((row => row.Split(',')))
                   .ToDictionary<string, Pair<string, string>>
                           (id => id[0],id => new Pair(id[1],id[1]));
```

This version of ToDictionary takes two functions, one that returns the key and one that returns the value for each item in the enumeration.

Comment: Shouldn't the second argument to `ToDictionary` be `id => new Pair(id[1],id[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide whether you want a tuple-based approach (or pair even) if you know how many items are in each row or if you need to consider that each row may have a different number of items.

```
// Setup sample data
var resultData = new
{
    Rows = new string[] { "1,A,B,C", "2,A,B", "3,A,B,C,D" }
};

// If same length for each row, tuple would work easily
// Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>
var tuples = resultData.Rows
    .Select(r => r.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(
        r => r[0],
        r => Tuple.Create(r[1], r[2])
    );

// If length is variable, then some type of collection could be better
// Dictionary<string, List<string>> 
var lists = resultData.Rows
    .Select(r => r.Split(','))
    .ToDictionary(
        r => r[0],
        r => r.Skip(1).ToList() // Skip adding id element
    );
```

Here is the output for the 1st item to compare each:

```
?lists["1"]
Count = 3
    [0]: "A"
    [1]: "B"
    [2]: "C"
?tuples["1"]
{(A, B)}
    Item1: "A"
    Item2: "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The original code block is here (with a generic dictionary). The reason I am changing this is due to the fact that if there is more than 1 value per key, the application errors out due to duplicate keys.

Seems like what you are looking for is [`ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx)

*"**`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`**
    represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values."*

.

```
var idDictionary = resultData.Rows.Select((row => row.Split(',')))
                   .ToLookup(id => id[0], id => id[1]);
```

**EDIT**

A short sample:

```
var lines = new string[] { "a,b", "a,c", "d,e" };
var dict = lines.Select(line => line.Split(','))
            .ToLookup(x => x[0], x => x[1]);

result: 
    Key: a   Value: [b,c]
    Key: e   Value: [e]
```

Sample usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", dict["a"]));
```

Comment: Eser, thank you and I have tried this solution, but I end up with a "key not found" error instead. Perhaps I am doing something wrong as I have never used ToLookup, Could you provide a more elaborate example? How the rest of the blocked needs to be changed? I'm not opposed to this, but having a harder time grasping how this change works with the whole block.

Comment: @booksguy It is very similar to dictionary. What do you want to do with Lookup/Dictionary exactly? A short example showing how you get *key not found*?

Comment: var idDictionary = resultData.Rows.Select((row => row.Split(','))).ToLookup(id => id[0], id => id[1]);
            idDictionary.ForEach(id => WriteLog("Input Id = {0} - Matching record Id = {1}", id.Key));
            var processList = data.Where(item => idDictionary.Contains(keyFilter(item.DataItem))).ToList();
            processList.ForEach(item => item.Id = idDictionary[keyFilter(item.DataItem)]);
            return processList;

Comment: @booksguy your code isn't even compilable. See my edit.

Comment: I have pasted the way I handled the ToLookup changes, but I know I'm not doing it right. To be more clear of my needs, the application takes the first column in the CSV as the key, requests the matching value from the system. Due to some unforeseen issues, the system has multiple values per key in some cases. I need to fix this block of code so it can iterate through each value instead of key, and submit the note (second column of the CSV) to each value. I hope that makes, sense, I will edit if not.

Comment: @booksguy `so it can iterate through each value instead of key`  I can't still get your issues but you can iterate on values (using my sample in answer) like this `dict.Where(x => x.Contains("c")).Select(x => x.Key);` I hope this make sense.